Error on Using AutoComplete Widget (showing error controller is dispose)
when i am using AutoComplete widget in flutter to take name from list and fill manually also .Now i want to assign a value to its controller and close screen .its ok but if open again it show error , controller is dispose
import 'package:shunya_core/models/claims_model/claims_list_model.dart' as c;


class OfficeAndEpcExpenseScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  cData.Data? data;
  String userLoginId;
  String expenseTypeId;
  c.Data? voucherData;
  OfficeAndEpcExpenseScreen({super.key, required this.data, required this.userLoginId, required this.expenseTypeId, this.voucherData});

  @override
  State<OfficeAndEpcExpenseScreen> createState() => _OfficeAndEpcExpenseScreenState();
}

class _OfficeAndEpcExpenseScreenState extends State<OfficeAndEpcExpenseScreen> {

  late AppLocalizations appLanguage;
  final OfficeAndEpcController _controller = Get.put(OfficeAndEpcController());

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    onInIt();
  }
  onInIt(){
    _controller.fileMaxSize.value = false;
    _controller.onAssignBillerList(widget.data!.vendors);
    if(widget.voucherData != null){
      log('Moit tnilllsdf');
      _controller.onAutoFillVoucherData(voucherData: widget.voucherData);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    _controller.selectedEntityId.value = null;
    _controller.selectedGlcId.value = null;
    _controller.selectedPaymentModeId.value = null;
    _controller.selectedBillerId.value = null;
    _controller.billAmount.clear();
    _controller.billNumber.clear();
    _controller.billDate.clear();
    _controller.purposeOfExpenseController.clear();
    // _controller.billerNameData.clear();
    // // _controller.billerNameList!.clear();
    _controller.filePath.value = null;
    _controller.fileName.value = '';
    _controller.fileExt.value = '';
    // _controller.billerNameController.text = '';

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mq = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    appLanguage = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
    return Expanded(
      child: Form(
        key: _controller.formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              _buildEntityTypeAndGlcField(),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              _buildBillNumberField(),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              _buildBillDateAndBilAmountField(),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              _buildBillerNameAndPaymentMode(),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              _buildPurposeOfExpense(),
              const SizedBox(height: 40),
              _buildFilePickerSection(),
              const SizedBox(height: 100,),
              _buildSaveButton(appLanguage: appLanguage, mq: mq),
              const SizedBox(height: 15),
            ],
          ),),),);
  }

  Widget _buildEntityTypeAndGlcField(){
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        // Expanded(
        //   child: CommonWidgets.buildDropdownField(label: appLanguage.entity_type, items: widget.data!.entityTypes!.map((v)=>v.entityType).toList(),
        //       onChanged: (val){
        //     _controller.onEntityTypeOnChanged(val: val!, data: widget.data);
        //       }, hint: appLanguage.please_select, fontSize: mq.height * 0.016, value: null,validator: (val){
        //         if(val != null && !val.isBlank!){
        //           return null;
        //         }else{
        //           return appLanguage.required;
        //         }
        //       }),),
        Expanded(child: CommonWidgets.buildDropdownField<String>(
          label: appLanguage.entity_type,
          items: widget.data!.entityTypes!.map((expenseType) {
            return expenseType.entityTypeId.toString(); // Use ID as item
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (selectedId) {
            if (selectedId != null) {
              _controller.onEntityTypeOnChanged(selectedId: selectedId, data: widget.data, voucherData: null);
            }
          },
          hint: appLanguage.please_select,
          fontSize: mq.height * 0.016, // Adjust font size as needed
          value: _controller.selectedEntityId.value, // The currently selected expenseTypeId
          displayItem: (id) {
            final entityType = widget.data!.entityTypes!.firstWhere(
                  (type) => type.entityTypeId.toString() == id,
              orElse: () => cData.EntityTypes(entityTypeId: int.parse(id), entityType: ''),
            );
            return entityType.entityType ?? ''; // Display the expense name
          },
        )),
        const SizedBox(width: 10,),

        // Expanded(
        //   child: CommonWidgets.buildDropdownField(label: appLanguage.glc, items: widget.data!.glcs!.map((v)=>v.glcName).toList(),
        //       onChanged: (val){
        //     _controller.onGlcListOnChanged(val: val!, data: widget.data);
        //       }, hint: appLanguage.please_select, fontSize: mq.height * 0.016, value: null,validator: (val){
        //         if(val != null && !val.isBlank!){
        //           return null;
        //         }else{
        //           return appLanguage.required;
        //         }
        //       }),)
        Expanded(child: CommonWidgets.buildDropdownField<String>(
          label: appLanguage.glc,
          items: widget.data!.glcs!.map((glcs) {
            return glcs.glcId.toString(); // Use ID as item
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (selectedId) {
            if (selectedId != null) {
              _controller.onGlcListOnChanged(selectedId: selectedId,data: widget.data, voucherData: null);
            }
          },
          hint: appLanguage.please_select,
          fontSize: mq.height * 0.016, // Adjust font size as needed
          value: _controller.selectedGlcId.value, // The currently selected expenseTypeId
          displayItem: (id) {
            final glcType = widget.data!.glcs!.firstWhere(
                  (type) => type.glcId.toString() == id,
              orElse: () => cData.Glcs(glcId: id, glcName: ''),
            );
            return glcType.glcName ?? ''; // Display the expense name
          },
        )),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBillNumberField(){
    return CommonWidgets.buildTextField(appLanguage: appLanguage, label: appLanguage.bill_number.replaceAll('*', ''),
      controller: _controller.billNumber, hint: appLanguage.enter_number, maxLines: 1,
      onChanged: (val){ },
      onTap: () async{ },validator: (val){
          if(val != null && !val.isBlank!){
            return null;
          }else{
            return appLanguage.required;
          }
        }
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBillDateAndBilAmountField(){
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Expanded(child: CommonWidgets.buildTextField(appLanguage: appLanguage, label: appLanguage.bill_date,
            controller: _controller.billDate, hint: 'dd/mm/yyyy', maxLines: 1,
            onChanged: (val){ },
            onTap: () async{
              DateTime firstD = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 365));
              final date = await CommonMethods.onDatePicker(context: context, initialDate: DateTime.now(), firstDate: firstD, lastDate: DateTime.now(),);
              if (date != null) {
                String? d = CommonMethods.showFormattedDate(date, formatFor: 1);
                _controller.billDate.text = d ?? '';
              }
            },
            inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)],
            validator: (val){
              if(val != null && !val.isBlank!){
                return null;
              }else{
                return appLanguage.required;
              }
            })),
        const SizedBox(width: 10,),
        Expanded(child: CommonWidgets.buildTextField(appLanguage: appLanguage, label: appLanguage.bill_amount,
            controller: _controller.billAmount, hint: appLanguage.enter_amount, maxLines: 1,
            onChanged: (val){ },
            onTap: () async{ },
            validator: (val){
              if(val != null && !val.isBlank!){
                return null;
              }else{
                return appLanguage.required;
              }
            })),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBillerNameAndPaymentMode(){
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Expanded(child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            CommonMethods.onAutoSizeText(appLanguage.biller_name),
            const SizedBox(height: 7),
            Autocomplete<cData.Vendors>(
              optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
                return _filterBillerNameList(textEditingValue.text);
              },
              onSelected: (cData.Vendors selectedVendor) {
                _controller.onBillerSelected(selectedVendor);
                _controller.billerNameControllerFocusNode.unfocus();
              },
              fieldViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                  TextEditingController textEditingController,
                  FocusNode focusNode,
                  VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted) {
                _controller.billerNameController = textEditingController;
                _controller.billerNameControllerFocusNode = focusNode;
                return TextFormField(
                  controller: textEditingController,
                  focusNode: focusNode,
                  decoration: CommonMethods.onTextFieldDecoration(hintText: appLanguage.enter_name),
                  onChanged: (text) {
                    // Check if the entered text matches any vendor
                    var matchingVendors = _controller.billerNameData.where((vendor) {
                      return vendor.vendorName?.toLowerCase() == text.toLowerCase();
                    }).toList();

                    if (matchingVendors.isEmpty) {
                      // If no vendor matches, set selectedBillerId.value to "0"
                      _controller.selectedBillerId.value = "0";
                    }

                  },onTap: () {
                  // Refocus and show filtered list when user taps on the text field again
                  if (!_controller.billerNameControllerFocusNode.hasFocus) {
                    _controller.billerNameControllerFocusNode.requestFocus(); // Focus on the text field
                  }
                },
                  validator: (val) {
                    if (val != null && val.isNotEmpty) {
                      return null;
                    } else {
                      return appLanguage.required;
                    }
                  },
                );
              },
              optionsViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                  AutocompleteOnSelected<cData.Vendors> onSelected,
                  Iterable<cData.Vendors> options) {

                double maxDropdownHeight = 300.0; // Maximum height for the dropdown
                double minDropdownHeight = 110.0; // Minimum height for the dropdown
                double itemHeight = 48.0; // Approximate height of each item
                double calculatedHeight = itemHeight * options.length; // Calculate height based on number of items

                // Ensure height is at least minDropdownHeight but not more than maxDropdownHeight
                double dropdownHeight = calculatedHeight.clamp(minDropdownHeight, maxDropdownHeight);

                return Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Material(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 80,
                      height: dropdownHeight,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: options.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          final cData.Vendors vendor = options.elementAt(index);
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              onSelected(vendor);
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(vendor.vendorName ?? '', style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                                  Divider(thickness: 1, color: AppColors.grey),
                                ],),
                            ),);},
                      ),),),
                );},)
          ],),),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        Expanded(child: CommonWidgets.buildDropdownField<String>(
          label: appLanguage.payment_mode,
          items: widget.data!.paymentModes!.map((paymentMode) {
            return paymentMode.paymentModeId.toString(); // Use ID as item
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (selectedId) {
            if (selectedId != null) {
              _controller.onPaymentModeOnChanged(selectedId: selectedId,data: widget.data, voucherData: null);
            }
          },
          hint: appLanguage.please_select,
          fontSize: mq.height * 0.016, // Adjust font size as needed
          value: _controller.selectedPaymentModeId.value, // The currently selected expenseTypeId
          displayItem: (id) {
            final pMode = widget.data!.paymentModes!.firstWhere(
                  (type) => type.paymentModeId.toString() == id,
              orElse: () => cData.PaymentModes(paymentModeId: int.parse(id), paymentMode: ''),
            );
            return pMode.paymentMode ?? ''; // Display the expense name
          },
        )),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPurposeOfExpense(){
    return CommonWidgets.buildTextField(appLanguage: appLanguage, label: appLanguage.description,
      controller: _controller.purposeOfExpenseController, hint: '', maxLines: 1,
      onChanged: (val){ },
      onTap: () async{ },
        validator: (val){
          if(val != null && !val.isBlank!){
            return null;
          }else{
            return appLanguage.required;
          }
        }
    );
  }

  Future<Iterable<cData.Vendors>> _filterBillerNameList(String query) async {
    if (query.isEmpty && _controller.billerNameControllerFocusNode.hasFocus) {
      return _controller.billerNameData;
    } else {
      return _controller.billerNameData
          .where((vendor) => vendor.vendorName?.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()) ?? false)
          .toList();
    }
  }

  Widget _buildFilePickerSection() {
    return Obx(() {
      final filePath = _controller.filePath.value;
      final fileName = _controller.fileName.value;

      return Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                AutoSizeText('${appLanguage.photo} :',
                    style: CommonMethods.getTextStyleBold(
                        fontSize: mq.height * 0.015, fontColor: Colors.black)),
                AutoSizeText('(${appLanguage.file_max_size_is_2mb})', style: TextStyle(fontSize: mq.height * 0.01, color: _controller.fileMaxSize.value ? AppColors.red : AppColors.black),)
              ],),
          ),
          const Spacer(),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: _controller.onFilePicker,
                  child: filePath != null
                      ? _buildFileContainer(filePath, fileName)
                      : _buildPlaceholderContainer(),
                ),
              ],),
          ),],);
    });
  }

  Widget _buildFileContainer(File file, String fileName) {
    // Check if it's an image file
    final isImage = fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith('.jpg') ||
        fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith('.png') ||
        fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith('.jpeg');
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 90,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(width: 1),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      ),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        child: isImage
            ? Image.file(file, width: 90, height: 115, fit: BoxFit.fill)  // Show image
            : const Center(child: Icon(Icons.picture_as_pdf, size: 40)),  // Show PDF icon
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPlaceholderContainer() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 90,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          ),
          child: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo, size: 40),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSaveButton({required AppLocalizations appLanguage, required Size mq}) {

    return CommonMethods.onMainAppButton(textLength: 0, maxTextLength: 0, text: appLanguage.save, height: 46, fontSize: mq.height * 0.025, clr: AppColors.lightblue,
        onTap: (){
          // if(_controller.filePath.value != null){
          //   log('file2');
          //     _controller.isFileSelected.value = false;
          // }else{
          //   _controller.isFileSelected.value = true;
          // }
          if(_controller.filePath.value == null){
            _controller.fileMaxSize.value = false;
          }
          if(_controller.fileMaxSize.value == false){
            if(_controller.formKey.currentState!.validate()){
              _controller.onSaveOfficeAndEpcExpense(context: context, appLanguage: appLanguage, userLoginId: widget.userLoginId, expenseTypeId: widget.expenseTypeId);
              log('Success validate');
            }else{
              log('Failed validate');}
          }
        });
  }
}

import 'package:shunya_core/models/claims_model/claim_reimbursement_data_model.dart' as cData;
import 'package:shunya_core/models/claims_model/claims_list_model.dart' as c;


class OfficeAndEpcController extends GetxController {

  RxnString selectedEntityId = RxnString();
  RxnString selectedGlcId = RxnString();
  RxnString selectedPaymentModeId = RxnString();
  TextEditingController billNumber = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController billDate = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController billAmount = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController purposeOfExpenseController = TextEditingController();
  // RxBool isFileSelected = RxBool(false);

  Rx<File?> filePath = Rx<File?>(null);  // This will hold both image or PDF file
  RxString fileName = ''.obs;
  RxString fileBase64 = ''.obs;
  RxString fileExt = ''.obs;
  RxBool fileMaxSize = false.obs;

  RxList<cData.Vendors> billerNameData = RxList<cData.Vendors>();
  RxnString selectedBillerId = RxnString();
  TextEditingController billerNameController = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode billerNameControllerFocusNode = FocusNode();
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  onAssignBillerList(List<cData.Vendors>? l) {
    log('OnBillerName ka listt ');
    billerNameData!.value = l ?? [];
    log('OnBillerName ka listt2  :: $billerNameData');
  }

  onBillerSelected(cData.Vendors selectedVendor) {
    billerNameController.text = selectedVendor.vendorName ?? '';
    // You can store the selected vendor's ID in a variable
    selectedBillerId.value = selectedVendor.vendorId;
  }

  onEntityTypeOnChanged(
      {required String selectedId, cData.Data? data, c.Data? voucherData}) {
    if(voucherData == null){
      if(data != null){
        // Find the ExpenseTypes object that matches the selected expenseTypeId
        var selectedEntityType = data!.entityTypes!
            .firstWhere((expenseType) => expenseType.entityTypeId.toString() == selectedId);

        // Set the selectedExpenseId and log it
        selectedEntityId.value = selectedEntityType.entityTypeId.toString();
        // Optionally log or update other fields if needed
        log('Selected Expense Type ID1 :: $selectedEntityType');
        log('Selected Expense Name1 :: ${selectedEntityType.entityTypeId}');
      }
    }else{

      // Set the selectedExpenseId
      selectedEntityId.value = selectedId;
      // Optionally log or update other fields if needed
      log('Selected Expense Type ID2 :: ');
      log('Selected Expense Name2 :: ');
    }
  }

  onGlcListOnChanged(
      {required String selectedId, cData.Data? data, c.Data? voucherData}) {
    if(voucherData == null){
      if(data != null){
        // Find the ExpenseTypes object that matches the selected expenseTypeId
          var selectedGlc = data!.glcs!
              .firstWhere((glcList) => glcList.glcId.toString() == selectedId);

          selectedGlcId.value = selectedGlc!.glcId.toString();
        // Optionally log or update other fields if needed
        log('Selected Glcc Type ID1 :: $selectedGlc');
        log('Selected Glc Name1 :: ${selectedGlc.glcId}');
      }
    }else{

      // Set the selectedExpenseId
      selectedGlcId.value = selectedId;
      // Optionally log or update other fields if needed
      log('Selected Expense Type ID2 :: ');
      log('Selected Expense Name2 :: ');
    }
  }

  onPaymentModeOnChanged(
      {required String selectedId, cData.Data? data, c.Data? voucherData}) {
    if(voucherData == null){
      if(data != null){
        // Find the ExpenseTypes object that matches the selected expenseTypeId
        var selectedPaymentModeType = data!.paymentModes!
            .firstWhere((pMode) => pMode.paymentModeId.toString() == selectedId);

        // Set the selectedExpenseId and log it
        selectedPaymentModeId.value = selectedPaymentModeType.paymentModeId.toString();
        // Optionally log or update other fields if needed
        log('Selected Payment Type ID1 :: $selectedPaymentModeType');
        log('Selected Payment Mode Name1 :: ${selectedPaymentModeType.paymentModeId}');
      }
    }else{

      // Set the selectedExpenseId
      selectedPaymentModeId.value = selectedId;
      // Optionally log or update other fields if needed
      log('Selected Expense Type ID2 :: ');
      log('Selected Expense Name2 :: ');
    }
  }

  Future<void> onFilePicker() async {
    // Reset file
    filePath.value = null;
    fileName.value = '';
    fileBase64.value = '';
    fileExt.value = '';
    fileMaxSize.value = false;

    // Ask user for file type
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      allowMultiple: false,
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'pdf'], // Restricting to image and PDF formats
    );

    if (result != null && result.files.single.path != null) {
      final selectedFile = File(result.files.single.path!);
      fileName.value = result.files.single.name;

      // If it's an image, compress it
      if (result.files.single.extension != null && ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'].contains(result.files.single.extension!.toLowerCase())) {
        filePath.value = selectedFile;
        final compressedImage = await PickFileAndCompress.onSingleImageCompressor(
          imageFile: selectedFile,
          atQuality: 55,
        );
        filePath.value = compressedImage;
        fileBase64.value = await PickFileAndCompress.imageToBase64(filePath.value?.path ?? '');

      } else if (result.files.single.extension != null && result.files.single.extension!.toLowerCase() == 'pdf') {
        // Check PDF size
        int pdfSizeInBytes = await selectedFile.length();
        if (pdfSizeInBytes > 2 * 1024 * 1024) { // Check if size is greater than 2 MB
          // Show a toast message
          // log('Pdf size id more  :: $pdfSizeInBytes');
          fileMaxSize.value = true;
          return; // Exit the function to prevent further processing
        }else{
          fileMaxSize.value = false;
          // Compress the PDF
          filePath.value = selectedFile;
          final compressPdf = await PickFileAndCompress.compressPdf(filePath.value!);
          filePath.value = compressPdf;
          fileBase64.value = await PickFileAndCompress.imageToBase64(filePath.value?.path ?? '');
        }

      }

      if (fileName.value.length >= 3) {
        fileExt.value = fileName.value.substring(fileName.value.length - 3);
        // log("File extension: ${fileExt.value}"); // Output: "pdf"
      } else {
        log("Filename is too short to determine extension.");
      }
    }
  }

  onSaveOfficeAndEpcExpense({required BuildContext context,
    required AppLocalizations appLanguage, required String userLoginId, required String expenseTypeId}) async {
    String? formattedDate = CommonMethods.showFormattedDate(billDate.text, formatFor: 2);
    final body = {
      "control": CommonMethods.getControlMap(),
      "data": {
        "voucher_id": "0",
        "employee_id": "0",
        "expense_type_id": expenseTypeId,
        "expense_purpose": purposeOfExpenseController.text.toString(),
        "payment_mode_id": selectedPaymentModeId.value,
        "entity_id": selectedEntityId.value,
        "bill_no": billNumber.text.toString(),
        "bill_date": formattedDate,
        "total_amount": billAmount.text.toString(),
        "biller_id": selectedBillerId.value,
        "biller_name": billerNameController.text.toString(),
        "cgst_amount": "0",
        "sgst_amount": "0",
        "igst_amount": "0",
        "glc_id": selectedGlcId.value,
        "user_login_id": userLoginId,
        "is_active": "1",
        "file_ext": filePath.value != null ? fileExt.value : '',
        "voucher_image" : filePath.value != null ? fileBase64.value : ''
      }
    };

    final response = await ApiClient.fetchPostWithToast(ApiConst.claimAddOfficeExpenseApiUrl, body, true, false);

    if(response != null){
      var res = response['response'];
      var message = response['message'];

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        // Clear list and show response dialog
        CommonMethods.showResponseDialog(
            context: context,
            title: appLanguage.message,
            msg: message,
            buttonText: appLanguage.ok,
            popTimes: 2,
            refreshKey: 'refreshClaimList'
        );
      }else{
        CommonMethods.showResponseDialog(
            context: context,
            title: appLanguage.message,
            msg: message,
            buttonText: appLanguage.ok,
            popTimes: 1
        );
      }
    }

  }

  onAutoFillVoucherData({required c.Data? voucherData}){
    onEntityTypeOnChanged(selectedId: voucherData!.entityId ?? '', voucherData: voucherData);
    onGlcListOnChanged(selectedId: voucherData.glcId ?? '', voucherData: voucherData);
    onPaymentModeOnChanged(selectedId: voucherData.paymentModeId ?? '', voucherData: voucherData);
    billNumber.text = voucherData.billNo ?? '';
    String? dateFormatted = CommonMethods.showFormattedDate(voucherData.voucherDate ?? '', formatFor: 1);
    billDate.text = dateFormatted ?? '';
    billAmount.text = voucherData.totalAmount ?? '';
    purposeOfExpenseController.text = voucherData.expensePurpose ?? '';
    onBillerOnChange(voucherData.vendorName ?? '');
  }

  onBillerOnChange(text){
    var matchingVendors = billerNameData.where((vendor) {
      return vendor.vendorName?.toLowerCase() == text.toLowerCase();
    }).toList();

    log('BillerName1 :: $text');
    if (matchingVendors.isEmpty) {
      // If no vendor matches, set selectedBillerId.value to "0"
      selectedBillerId.value = "0";
      log('BillerName2 :: $selectedBillerId');
    }else{
      selectedBillerId.value = "1";
      billerNameController.text = text;
      log('BillerName3 :: $text');
      log('BillerName4 :: $selectedBillerId');
    }
  }

}

I tried resetting the controller and restarting the mobile app , also changed the logic of controller to not get disposed , still its getting disposed

Based on your mentioned scenario, Pass the Controller from the main.dart file and declare the controller in the main.dart file. So, the controller will not dispose when the screen is closed.
